# RAILS: Relations (Select all answers from all topics)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, database-relations

**category.rb**

```
  has_many :topics
```

**topic.rb**

```
belongs_to :category
has_many :answers
```

**answer.rb**

```
belongs_to :topic
```

**Question:**

How can i preform queries like `Category.first.topics.answers.count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `has_many :through` relation:

```
# Category.rb
has_many :topics
has_many :answers, through: :topics
```

Now you can access all answers from all topics like so:

```
Category.first.answers.count
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are set on your schema configuration (i.e. not using a `has_many :through`), you'd want to start with `Answers` and utilize a couple of `join`s to get to `Category`

```
Answers.joins(topic: :category).where(categories: { id: category_id })
```

here we're joining on a nested association, and then using a where clause to filter out by the `category_id`

note: i think this is the right syntax, but you may need to fiddle around with the plurality of `topic` and `category` there

Comment: I truly forgotten about has_many :through, but it is always great to have many solutions of 1 problem. Thank you!